# C assign an int to a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I have an function address stored in an `unsigned int`, and a function pointer.

Now i want that `function_pointer` will contain the value of  `function_address`

```
unsigned int function_address = 0xdeadbeef;
void(*function_pointer)(void) = function_address; // not valid
```

how to do that in C ?

Comment: PSA: Do not use `unsigned int` to store addresses. On some platforms (like x86_64 Linux), an `int` is smaller than a pointer. Use the type `uintptr_t` for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perform an explicit cast.

```
void(*function_pointer)(void) = (void (*)(void))function_address;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
typedef void(*function_pointer_type)(void)
function_pointer_type *function_pointer = (function_pointer_type *) address;
```